# Attack against factorization of $p-1$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ group

Tags: group-theory

[It is said](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9011/59088) that for the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, the factorization of  $p-1$, is critical.

If $p-1$ has some small factors $q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4$, then when we transmit $g^x \bmod p$ where $g$ is a generator of this group, the attacker can derive $x \bmod q_1q_2q_3q_4$

How does it happen?

Can someone please provide a practical example, say for $p = 29$, where $p$ is prime but $p-1$ has a bunch of small factors?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Pohling-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm#The_general_algorithm)? Any remaining question after that?

Comment: You can easily find example. Take a look at [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52724/pohlig-hellman-algorithm) for instance.